# Central Locking on Trunk Lock doesn't work? Manual lock works (Seat Cordoba 1.6 gasoline 2000)

Tags: locks, electronics, seat-cars, trunk, central-locking

I have a SEAT Cordoba 1.6 from the year 2000, gasoline engine version:
[image]

I noticed that when pushing the 'LOCK' button on the (wireless) key that all doors, except the trunk door, lock. Manually locking/unlocking works.

I decided to take off the trunk panel and to check the voltage that is applied to the motor that handles the lock - when locking it's -1.7V and when unlocking it's 1.7V (or the other way around, forgot, sorry). I think that is way too low. I checked the motor and it works - I applied 5 volts too it from a USB power supply, but I think it's a small 12V motor as it sounded a bit "powerless" at 5V (or the USB power supply couldn't provide enough current, but the supply is rated for 2Amps). Thinking 1.7V would be enough I didn't want to destroy the DC motor so I applied 5V, nothing more, it still works, I put it back in, got back to the car, put the panels back on, and I'm back where I started.

I tried looking where to find the fuse box and wiring diagram for the SEAT Cordoba 1.6 version, so I could check which fuse is responsible for the trunk lock, because I think the issue might reside there, but I can't find it anywhere.

How would I go about fixing this issue so the central lock will work on the trunk door too? Any tips? Resources to find wiring/fuse diagrams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have any wiring diags for that car but you can tell its not a fuse since you are getting some voltage.

First thing is first you need to determine what voltage that motor is supposed to get and if it has a model number on the motor's casing you may be able to find that on Google. If it says 1.7V then there might be an issue with the brushes or some other problem that will warrant replacing the motor or gear set for the lock release.

I suspect just as you suspect that it is a 12V motor. This means you will need to trace the wire to wherever its break or short is and repair it there. This is where a wiring diagram will come in handy. Call the dealer see if they will email you the page you are looking for. You can also usually ask a local library to stock that cars shop manual and many times they will pick it up. Lastly go to a parts store and ask them for the diagram many non big retail chains will be able to pull it up for you.

It is not directly what you are looking for but there seems to be a fair number of wiring diagrams for that car on google images [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=SEAT%20Cordoba%202000%20wiring&safe=active&biw=1750&bih=917&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC6LaSppTQAhVrsFQKHbgaDzYQ_AUIBigB)

you can use a tone generator to trace the wires like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0HjaR0tj7Q). As an IT guy who does networking these are invaluable, well actually they only cost about $30.

Comment: Alright I will try this advice! Thank you for your time, will let know shortly if anything progresses :)

Comment: Cool. The last thing to note is you may have a bad ground as well. The trunk is on a hinge and if that is bolted to the top hinged opening part possibly a ground is loose. One tip from being an IT guy is you may be able to put a tone on the wire with a tone generator and then use a tracer to find where it goes. This is especially useful when you have a bundle of wires in a conduit.

Comment: Smart use of our IT tools! (jup I work in IT too xD) Will definitely check that too

Comment: I run an IT company but am really good with cars. they are mostly a big computer with pistons ;). Good luck I hope you find that weak point.

Comment: Well I can't seem to locate anything wrong, I'll take it to the mechanic :)

Comment: @Gizmo make sure they know electronics many mechanics do not know much about them. Mechanics that specialize in electronics will be what you want to look for. Did you try to touch a 12v battery to the terminals on the lock?

Comment: On the actuator itself only 5V - then it does work, to the terminals that go to the car not, too scared that I might destroy any fragile electronics.

Comment: Aha so the actuator is getting fed 5V that means some component went bad that deals in giving that lowered voltage. You can still trace the wire using a tone generator and more than likely the first box it goes too will be the one that is not giving the correct power. This is assuming it consistently gives that 1.7V when it is supposed to.